How to "enlarge" menu items/text
I have become visually impaired, struggling to read "the small print" (of Emacs 29.3).  How can I permanently change the size of the icons and text in the meny bar? I have been searching the net: negative. (Could be due to lack of "adequate" concepts.)

Are you talking about terminal Emacs or GUI Emacs? What OS are you running? It might be that text size in the menu bar is beyond Emacs's control. E.g. in my case I run a GTK-build of Emacs and I can change that size from the Accessibility menu of Gnome (my desktop environment) but not from Emacs AFAIK. OTOH, I can change the text size in Emacs windows, by changing the font size in Emacs. So if you can provide more details about your setup, that would help I think, but note that I am definitely not an expert and I may be way off-base.

Thank you, Nick, Sorry for leaving out these. I am on LinuxMint lTM (21. 3) Mate. My emacs is GUI, 27.1, GTK+ 3.24.3, Cairo 1.16.0). Inside the working window I can set and store font changes. They do not affect the menu bar/submenues. In "web-based" programs (Firefox, RStudio) C-+/ - will  change the working area,. In RStudio, the menu icons will also be affected, but not the font size. In Firefox C-+ do not affect the size of the menu icons or font. I have not tried to adjust the "overall" system font settings. I hope to find a solution tweaking emacs. Best regards Arne
